# Using a recursive function as output in a ostream function

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm overloading the ostream operator << to be able to print out or write down my ojbects. In one of these, I'm actually writting my whole structure inside a file.txt. The structure object is actually a binary tree and to make sure I'm getting every element out of it I need a recursive function. Here is a basic code of what I'm trying to do.

```
out << parcour(tree); // recursive function
```

Parcour is suppose to return anoter structure in which I have the informations to write in the output file. The inside of my recursive function goes something like this:

```
node* parcour(node* node){
      if (node) {
         parcour(childnode(0));
         parcour(childnode(1));
         return node;
      }
   return nullptr;
}
```

All the node with the informations I want are returned by this function. So I think the problem is that multiple returns into one single std::cout isn't actually working. I would like to know if there is anyway that a function with multiple return (a recursive function) could be taken as an ouput where every single return will be done one at a time.

Please don't pay attention to syntaxt error since my code is running perfectly except for that single concept that I can't resolve.

EDIT: Some people have been requesting me to give more code so basically I'll just copy paste the ORIGINAL CODE beneath(note: everything is in french :S):

This is Arbres.h

```
 #ifndef ARBRES_H
#define ARBRES_H
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// noeud pour un arbre binaire contenant des informations de type T
template <class T>
class Noeud
{
private:
    T* element; // élément du noeud
    Noeud<T> *parent; // Pointeur vers le parent
    Noeud<T> *gauche; // Pointeur vers le fils gauche
    Noeud<T> *droit; // Pointeur vers le fils droit

public:

//constructeur du noeud
    Noeud()
    {
        element = nullptr;
        parent = nullptr;
        gauche = nullptr;
        droit = nullptr;
    }

// destructeur du noeud
    ~Noeud ()
    {

    }

// retourne l'enfant où "i" represente la position de l'enfant (droit ou gauche)
    Noeud<T> * Enfant(int i) const
    {
        if (i == 0)
            if (!gauche)
                return nullptr;
            else
                return gauche;
        else if (i == 1)
            if (!droit)
                return nullptr;
            else
                return droit;
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

// retourne le parent du noeud
    Noeud<T> *Parent () const
    {
        return parent;
    }

// retourne un pointeur vers l'élément du noeud (les infos)
    T *Element() const
    {
        return element;
    }

// modifie la valeur de l'élément
    void RemplacerElement( T *ele )
    {
        element = ele;
    }

//retourne vrai si le noeud est une feuille
    bool EstUneFeuille () const
    {
        return (!gauche) && (!droit);
    }

//retourne vrai si le noeud est une racine
    bool EstUneRacine () const
    {
        return (!parent);
    }

// détache l'enfant du noeud et retourne un pointeur vers ce noeud
    Noeud<T> *Detacher (Noeud<T>* Enfant)
    {
        Noeud<T> *temp;

        if (Enfant->parent->gauche == Enfant) {
            temp = Enfant->parent->gauche;
            Enfant->parent->gauche = nullptr;
        } else if (Enfant->parent->droit == Enfant) {
            temp = Enfant->parent->droit;
            Enfant->parent->droit = nullptr;
        } else
            return nullptr;
        return temp;
    }

// attache le noeud à l'enfant. Retourne vrai si l'opération est réussie
    bool Attacher(Noeud<T>* nouvelEnfant)
    {
        if (!gauche)
            gauche = nouvelEnfant;
        else if(!droit)
            droit = nouvelEnfant;
        else
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }

// attache les enfants au noeud. Retourne vrai si l'opération est réussie
    bool Attache(Noeud<T>* noeudCourant)
    {
        if (!gauche->parent)
            gauche->parent = noeudCourant;
        else if (!droit->parent)
            droit->parent = noeudCourant;
        else
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }

// Fonction Récursive qui crée un nouveau noeud et le place correctement dans l'arbre
    void CreerNouveauNoeud(istream& in, Noeud<T>* noeudCourant, int val) {
        if (val == 1) {
            if (!noeudCourant->Enfant(0)) {
                noeudCourant->Attacher(new Noeud<T>());
                noeudCourant->Attache(noeudCourant);
                noeudCourant = noeudCourant->Enfant(0);
                noeudCourant->RemplacerElement(new T());
                in >> *(noeudCourant->Element());
                return;
            }
            else if (!noeudCourant->Enfant(1)) {
                noeudCourant->Attacher(new Noeud<T>());
                noeudCourant->Attache(noeudCourant);
                noeudCourant = noeudCourant->Enfant(1);
                noeudCourant->RemplacerElement(new T());
                in >> *(noeudCourant->Element());
                return;
            }
            else {
                cout << "\nERROR: Structure dans le fichier texte incorrect (limite de 2 sous-noeuds par noeud)" << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!noeudCourant->Enfant(1)) // S'il existe un noeud à droite s'est qu'on est rendu à ajouter la, sinon on va à gauche
                CreerNouveauNoeud(in, noeudCourant->Enfant(0), val - 1);
            else
                CreerNouveauNoeud(in, noeudCourant->Enfant(1), val - 1);
        }
        return;
    }

// le mot clé "friend" indique que la fonction peut utiliser les membres privés de la classe Noeud
    template<class U>
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Noeud<U>& n);

    template<class U>
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Noeud<U>& n);

};

// surcharge de l'opérateur >> pour un noeud
template <class T>
istream& operator>> (istream& in, Noeud<T>& n)
{
    in >> *n.element;
    return in;
}

// surcharge de l'opérateur << pour un noeud
template <class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Noeud<T>& n)
{
    out << *n.element;
    return out;
}


// Patron de classe définissant la classe "Arbres"
// contenant des informations de type T
template <class T>
class Arbres
{
// Patron de classe définissant la classe "Arbres"
private:
    vector<Noeud<T>*> racines;
    Noeud<T>* noeudCourant;

public:

//constructeur d'une classe Arbres
    Arbres()
    {
        noeudCourant = nullptr;
    }

// destructeur d'une classe Arbres
    ~Arbres ()
    {
        supprimeArbre();
    }

    // ajoute un arbre de niveau 0 (un noeud) à la liste des racines
    int NouveauNoeud(Noeud<T>* n)
    {
        n->RemplacerElement(new T());
        racines.push_back(n);
        return racines.size() - 1;
    }

    // positionne le noeud courant sur le noeud racine d'indice i
    void SetCourant(int i)
    {
        if(i<racines.size())
            noeudCourant = racines[i];
    }

    // Déplace le noeud courant vers son enfant i
    void NaviguerVersEnfant(int i)
    {
        noeudCourant = noeudCourant->Enfant(i);
    }

    // Déplace le noeud courant vers son parent
    void NaviguerVersParent()
    {
        noeudCourant = noeudCourant->Parent();
    }

    // mets le noeud en position i de la liste racine comme enfant du noeud courant
    void joindreCourant(int i)
    {
        if (!noeudCourant->Enfant(0) || !noeudCourant->Enfant(1)) {
            noeudCourant->Attacher(racines[i]);
            racines[i] = nullptr;
            racines.erase(racines.begin()+i);
        }
        else {
            cout << "/nERROR: Aucun Enfant disponible sur le noeud Courant " << endl;
        }
    }

    // Détache le noeud courant de son parent
    void DetacherCourant()
    {
        if (noeudCourant->Parent()->Enfant(0) == noeudCourant) {
            noeudCourant->Detacher(noeudCourant->Enfant(0));
        }
        else
            noeudCourant->Detacher(noeudCourant->Parent()->Enfant(1));
    }

    // supprime le noeud courant
    void SupprimerCourant()
    {
        supprimeArbre(noeudCourant);
    }

    // retourne la liste des noeuds racines
    const vector<Noeud<T>*>* getRacine() const
    {
        return &racines;
    }

    // retourne le noeud courant
    const Noeud<T>* getCourant() const
    {
        return noeudCourant;
    }

    // fonction récursive qui parcours l'arbre et retourne chacun d'entre eux
    void parcourir(ostream& out, Noeud<T>* racine) {
        if (racine) {
            parcourir(out, racine->Enfant(0));
            parcourir(out, racine->Enfant(1));
            out << *racine;
        }
        return;
    }

    void supprimeArbre(Noeud<T>* racine) { // fonction récursive qui parcours l'arbre et supprime chaque noeud que l'on rencontre
        if (racine) {
            supprimeArbre(racine->Enfant(0));
            supprimeArbre(racine->Enfant(1));
            delete racine->Element();
            delete racine;
        }
        return;
    }

// le mot clé "friend" indique que la fonction peut utiliser les membres privés d'une classe Arbres
    template<class U>
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Arbres<U>& n);

    template<class U>
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Arbres<U>& n);

};

// surcharge de l'opérateur >> pour un objet de type Arbres<T>
template <class T>
istream& operator>> (istream& in, Arbres<T>& n)
{
    string buffer;
    while (in >> buffer) {
        int a = count(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), '-'); // Compte le nombre de tiret pour déterminer le niveau du noeud dans l'arbres
        if (a == 0) {
            n.SetCourant(n.NouveauNoeud(new Noeud<T>()));
            n.noeudCourant->RemplacerElement(new T());
            in >> *(n.noeudCourant);
        }
        else {
            n.noeudCourant->CreerNouveauNoeud(in, n.noeudCourant, (a / 2));
        }
    }
    return in;
}

// surcharge de l'opérateur << pour un objet de type Arbres<T>
template <class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Arbres<T>& n) 
{
    for (int x = 0; x < n.racines.size(); x++) {
        n.parcourir(out, n.racines[x]);
    }
    return out;
}

#endif
```

This is TP2.h

```
#ifndef TP2_H
#define TP2_H
#pragma once
# include <string>
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Personne
{
    private:
        string nom;
        string prenom;
        int age;
        string metier;
    public:
        Personne();
        Personne(string leNom, string lePrenom, int lAge, string leMetier);
        ~Personne();

        friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Personne& n);
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Personne& n);
};

#endif
```

This is TP2.cpp

```
#include "TP2.h"
#include "Arbres.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

Personne::Personne() {
    return;
}

Personne::Personne(string leNom, string lePrenom, int lAge, string leMetier)
{
    nom = leNom;
    prenom = lePrenom;
    age = lAge;
    metier = leMetier;
    return;
}

Personne::~Personne()
{
    return;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, Personne& n)
{
    in >> n.nom >> n.prenom >> n.age >> n.metier;
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Personne& n)
{
    out << "\tNom: " << n.nom << "\n\tPrenom: " << n.prenom << "\n\tAge: " << n.age << "\n\tMetier: " << n.metier << endl;
    return out;
}

int main(){
    ifstream Transaction;
    ifstream Data_input;
    ofstream Data_ouput;
    string transaction_fichier;
    string arbres_fichier;
    char op[1], FILENAME[50]; // Operateur, Nom d'un fichier
    int i; // Indice
    Arbres<Personne>* structure = nullptr;
    cout << "Entrer le nom du fichier transaction: ";
    cin >> transaction_fichier; // IMPORTANT : Le nom du fichier ne doit pas compoter d'espace!
    cout << endl;
    Transaction.open(transaction_fichier);
    if (Transaction.fail())
        cout << "\nError 404 : File not found\n";
    while (!Transaction.eof()) {
        Transaction >> op;
        switch (op[0]) {
        case '*':
            Transaction >> *(*(structure->getRacine()))[structure->NouveauNoeud(new Noeud<Personne>())];
            break;
        case '&':
            Transaction >> i;
            structure->SetCourant(i);
            break;
        case '>':
            Transaction >> i;
            structure->NaviguerVersEnfant(i);
            break;
        case '<':
            Transaction >> i;
            structure->NaviguerVersParent();
            break;
        case '+':
            Transaction >> i;
            structure->joindreCourant(i);
            break;
        case '-':
            structure->DetacherCourant();
            break;
        case '!':
            structure->SupprimerCourant();
            break;
        case '%':
            cout << "Informations des personnes dans les noeuds racines:" << endl;
            for (unsigned int x = 0; x < (*(structure->getRacine())).size(); x++) {
                cout << *(*(structure->getRacine()))[x] << endl;
            }
            break;
        case '?':
            cout << "Informations de la personne dans le noeud courant:" << endl;
            cout << *(structure->getCourant()->Element()) << endl;
            break;
        case '#':
            if (structure) {
                for (unsigned int x = 0; x < (*(structure->getRacine())).size(); x++) {
                    structure->supprimeArbre((*(structure->getRacine()))[x]);
                }
            }
            else {
                Transaction >> FILENAME;
                Data_input.open(FILENAME);
                if (Data_input.fail())
                    cout << "\nError 404 : File not found\n";
                structure = new Arbres<Personne>;
                Data_input >> *structure;
            }
            break;
        case '$':
            Transaction >> FILENAME;
            Data_ouput.open(FILENAME);
            Data_ouput << *structure;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\nError420 Operator not supported: " << op << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Fin du programme
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not recursion.

Comment: @DimChtz How is a function calling itself a number of times not recursion?!

Comment: @AlexandreBlanchet Not sure what your question is, but are you sure you want to use `<<` with a `node` *pointer*?

Comment: @Biffen shame on me, I thought it cannot work...

Comment: please read again my post and you'll understand. You can pass a node pointer to << if you have a overloading function of the operator << friend of the actually class node. The way i wrote the function parcour is not 100% correct and i know that, it was just a simple example.

Comment: @AlexandreBlanchet Can you show us the `operator<<` you're using?

Comment: @AlexandreBlanchet I can't get an `operator<<` for a class to work with a pointer to an object of said class. Are you sure it works?

Comment: Ok since you guys were confused when my code is actually working fine there you go i copy paste it all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole recursive call is not working as you do expect it to run.
What gets outout is the *return* value returned from your toplevel `parcour()` call. As the internal recursive calls seem not to contribute to the return value, it is not important whether the calls occur or would just be skipped.

To achieve what you described to intend you woud need to pass in the output object to `parcour()` and do the output of whatever you need within that function.

Comment: "you woud need to pass in the output object to parcour() and do the output of whatever you need within that function." Thank you :)

Comment: @Biffen: The interesting part is the `<<` method implementation working on `node` (as this then would need to do a similar recursion inside). Some code needs to visit each node for doing the output. This is not recognizable from the code portions given.

Comment: Just wanted you not to be excluded from the response. I removed the stray remark from my answer. It did not invalidate the core of the problem addressed and could easily distract focus from the essential aspect.

Comment: @rpy Don't get me wrong; I agree with your answer (and upvoted accordingly), it was just the one detail that I thought needed fixed.

Comment: As you asked I added a bunch more code in the edit but my original code is huge so...yeah a bit messy but thank you i'm actually trying to pass the ostream as a parameters and use it to do the output inside the recursive function itself like you said @rpy