# Recursive ostream function c++

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, ostream

I have a class which has children of the same type, and I want to get data from them all with a function that takes an ostream reference. So far I have this code, but I am getting an error:

"invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'ostream')"

```
ostream& print(ostream& myOstream) {

    if(child!=nullptr){
        myOstream << child->write(myOstream);
    }

    myOstream << " " << objectData << " ";

    return myOstream;
}
```

I gather there's a problem with the functions return value and printing that to the ostream? I've been trying to fix this for quite a while so would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: `return myOstream` Maybe you mean.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. What's `child`? What's `out`? What's `objectData`? On which line the error is reported? How are you calling `print`?

Comment: You really need to learn how to ask questions, And its possibly a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292905/using-a-recursive-function-as-output-in-a-ostream-function .

Comment: What type does `child->write(myOstream)` return? I’m guessing that a function named `write` that takes a stream writes to that stream. If that’s the case, the write has been done and there’s nothing more needed; just call `child->write(myOstream)`. No `<<` needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't output the result of printing the child:

```
if (child != nullptr){
    child->write(myOstream);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I didn't try that earlier. Works perfect.